# Examples of a K3 surface in a product of $\mathbb P^1$'s

Tags: algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces

On the Wikipeida page for K3 surfaces,
there are several [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3_surface#Examples) listed of how to produce a K3 surface
as a subvariety of
projective space
by taking polynomials of specified degrees.
Namely, a K3 surface is cut out by

- a degree 4 polynomial in $\mathbb P^3$,
- a degree 2 and a degree 3 polynomial in $\mathbb P^4$, and
- three degree 2 polynomials in $\mathbb P^5$.

Are there similar examples
of how to get a  K3 surface
as an explicit subvariety of $\mathbb P^1 \times \cdots \times \mathbb P^1$?
Or is there a reason this is not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Huybrechts' book](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/K3Global.pdf) (1.4.1, page 18) gives an example in $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$:

> Smooth hypersurfaces $X \subset \mathbb P^2 \times \mathbb P^1$ and $X \subset \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ of type $(3, 2)$ and $(2, 2, 2)$, respectively, provide K3 surfaces.

Comment: Yet another example is the complete intersection of two divisors of type $(1,1,1,1)$ in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reference and answers!